# Force user to upload particular file type

Tags: file-upload

Is there anyway to make the user only upload image file by restricting the file types in "File Upload" dialog just like "Small File Upload Site" of SWF uploader here...

http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/multiinstancedemo/index.php

Answer (score -1):

You can set an accept attribute on the input element, like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

Which will work in some (most?) modern browsers.

Comment: Hi Joost, it is also providing an option to select the files of other types(by selecting all files). Please check the given link for the way i like to get.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't 100% guarantee that you will only get image files, there's just no way to guarantee that in plain HTML. If you do want that you'll have to use some browser plugin (like SWF upload does).